# Pandas volumes distribution

Tags: python, pandas

I have two DataFrame with orders and graphic
So in the following example:

```
import pandas as pd
In [119]: orders = pd.DataFrame({'area':['a','b','c'], 'code': [177, 23,10], 'requires':[10.0,3.0,6.0]})
graphic = pd.DataFrame({'area': ['a','a','a','c','c'], 'code': [177, 177,177,10,10], 
                        'date':['2022-06-11', '2022-06-12','2022-06-13','2022-07-01','2022-07-03'], 
                        'volume':[7.0,2.0,1.0,6.0,3.0]})
In [120]:orders
Out[120]:
   area   code   requires
0   a     177       10.0
1   b     23        3.0
2   c     10        6.0
In [121]:graphic
Out[121]:
  area  code    date    volume
0   a   177  2022-06-11  7.0
1   a   177  2022-06-12  2.0
2   a   177  2022-06-13  1.0
3   c   10   2022-07-01  6.0
4   c   10   2022-07-03  3.0
```

I need to set the date in orders if volume(graphic) is enough for requires *by keys area and code*. But if in graphic several dates we set that date where volume is accumulated. For example: for area - 'a' and code - '177' we need 10.0 kg and for date 2022-06-11 it's not enough and we see next date (7.0+2.0=9.0) and it's still not enough. And in 2022-06-13 (7.0+2.0+9.0 = 10.0) it is volume that required and we set this date (2022-06-13). If the required volume is not accumulated, we return NaN

Visually, the result I want would look like this:

```
area    code    requires    date
0   a   177       10.0    2022-06-13
1   b   23         3.0       NaN
2   c   10         6.0    2022-07-01
```

I solved it, but it takes a long time for 20000 rows. I believe that exists method that do it more elegant and faster

```
def data_shipment(city, code, required_to_make):
    if graphic[(graphic['area']==city) & (graphic['code']==code)].empty:
        return np.nan
    elif required_to_make == 0:
        return np.nan   
    elif graphic.loc[(graphic['area']==city) & (graphic['code']==code), 'volume'].iloc[0] >= required_to_make:   
        data_of_making = graphic.loc[(graphic['area']==city) & (graphic['code']==code) & (graphic['date']==graphic.loc[(graphic['area']==city) 
                                    & (graphic['code']==code), 'date'].iloc[0]),'date'].iloc[0]
        graphic.loc[(graphic['area']==city) & (graphic['code']==code) & (graphic['date']==data_of_making),
                    'volume'] -= required_to_make
        data = graphic[(graphic['area']==city) & (graphic['code']==code)]['date'].iloc[0]
        return data
    else:
        if len(graphic.loc[(graphic['area']==city) & (graphic['code']==code)]) == 1:
            return np.nan
        elif len(graphic.loc[(graphic['area']==city) & (graphic['code']==code)]) > 1:
            len_of_dates = len(graphic.loc[(graphic['area']==city) & (graphic['code']==code)])
            i = 0
            storage_var = graphic.loc[(graphic['area']==city) & (graphic['code']==code), 'volume'].iloc[0]
            list_of_dates_to_be_deleted = []
            while storage_var<required_to_make and len_of_dates>1:
                len_of_dates-=1
                i+=1
                storage_var+= graphic.loc[(graphic['area']==city) & (graphic['code']==code), 'volume'].iloc[i]
                list_of_dates_to_be_deleted.append(graphic.loc[(graphic['area']==city) & (graphic['code']==code) & 
                                             (graphic['date']==graphic.loc[(graphic['area']==city) 
                                            & (graphic['code']==code), 'date'].iloc[i-1]),
                                             'date'].iloc[0])                    
            if storage_var<required_to_make:
                return np.nan
            else:
                for j in (list_of_dates_to_be_deleted):
                    graphic.drop(graphic[(graphic['area']==city) & (graphic['code']==code) & 
                           (graphic['date']==j)].index, inplace=True)
                    i-=1
                data_of_making = graphic.loc[(graphic['area']==city) & (graphic['code']==code) & 
                                             (graphic['date']==graphic.loc[(graphic['area']==city) 
                                            & (graphic['code']==code), 'date'].iloc[i]),
                                             'date'].iloc[0]
            graphic.loc[(graphic['area']==city) & (graphic['code']==code) & 
                        (graphic['date']==data_of_making), 'volume'] = storage_var-required_to_make
 
            data = graphic[(graphic['area']==city) & (graphic['code']==code)]['date'].iloc[i] 
            return data
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution that uses `merge` and `groupby` to accomplish this in a cleaner and probably faster method (haven't benchmarked)

```
import pandas as pd

orders = pd.DataFrame(
    {"area": ["a", "b", "c"], "code": [177, 23, 10], "requires": [10.0, 3.0, 6.0]}
)


graphic = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "area": ["a", "a", "a", "c", "c"],
        "code": [177, 177, 177, 10, 10],
        "date": ["2022-06-11", "2022-06-12", "2022-06-13", "2022-07-01", "2022-07-03"],
        "volume": [7.0, 2.0, 1.0, 6.0, 3.0],
    }
)


# Add the cummulative sum of volume (per group)
graphic["volume_cumsum"] = graphic.groupby(["area", "code"])["volume"].cumsum()

# Join with orders to add the requires column
graphic = graphic.merge(orders, on=["area", "code"])

# Create a mask to leave only rows where requires is exceeded by the cumsum
required_exceeded_mask = graphic["volume_cumsum"] >= graphic["requires"]

# The minimal date where the requires was exceeded
min_exceeding_date = (
    graphic[required_exceeded_mask].groupby(["area", "code"])["date"].min()
)

# Merge the minimal date to the orders dataframe - while keeping missing values
result = orders.merge(
    min_exceeding_date, left_on=["area", "code"], right_index=True, how="outer"
)
```